# Odds: singular or plural?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, nouns

The following sentence, from my grammar textbook, confused me:

> What's the odds? (What does it matter?)

I looked up *odds* in some dictionaries. All say that *odds* is a plural noun. So, there are two questions:

1) Why can *is* be used after a plural noun?

2) Is there any singular form of *odds*? What exactly is an *odd*?

Answer (score 2):

I think you found a typo in your book! 
It should read: "What're (What are) the odds?"

Here are some other examples of plural nouns in English that don't have a singular equivalent but sometimes get conjugated as singular:

- Scissors
- Pants

Even though the singular conjugation is not correct it still shows up, especially in conversation. "Media" is a great example of this, since it is actually a plural of "medium" but almost never is used as a plural.

Comment: It is not uncommon in casual speech for people to contract "there are" to "there's", even though that's not a correct contraction.  For example: "There's three books on the table." So it might not be a typo, but it is very sloppy to have this in a grammar book!

Answer (score 1):

The Google definition is

> odds, plural noun:
>   the ratio between the amounts staked by the parties to a bet, based on the expected probability either way.

Notice that the definition is *the* ratio (as in, there is by definition only one ratio). So, even though the noun **odds** is plural, when you replace the word with it's definition, it would switch from "What are the odds?" to "What is the probability?"¹. While **odd** is a word with its own definition, you cannot use it as a singular form to **odds**. It's similar to the word **clothes**; you wear **clothes**, but you do not say that your pants or shirt are each a **cloth**.

¹ **Odds** (ratio) and probability are different but related terms in statistics, but when using them in a non-statistcal context, they are generally interchangeable.